# Cordova publish Android through windows cmd - signing issue

Tags: windows, cordova, cmd, apk, publish

I am trying to publish the APK to the Playstore.
On the Playstore console I have generated the deployment_cert.der

I have set the environment variables and Cordova is able to create the APK but it gives me the following warnings and errors:

> 'keystore' and 'alias' need to be specified to generate a signed
>   archive

But I am adding those to the build command:

> cordova run android --release -- --keystore={pathj}.keystore
>   --storePassword={pword}-- alias={alias name} --password={pword}

The final error message is:

> Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Package
>   /data/app/vmdl1570063268.tmp/base.apk has no certificates at entry
>   AndroidManifest.xml]

So, my questions are as follows, do I download the deployment_cert.der and place it somewhere in the cordova project files? If so do I reference this in the config.xml?

Has anyone else had this trouble? Can you spot where I am failing?
Any assitance is appreciated

Comment: This has nothing to do with Windows CMD or really Windows. Ask Android people not Windows people.

Comment: @Noodles Aye, I get that, but it is to do with file placement and commands in a Windows environment. The question is posed to windows users who have encountered the same problem. In reality I am not really interacting with Android files and systems. It is all done behind the scenes for me with Cordova and the cmd